# Meson equivalent of automake's CONFIG_STATUS_DEPENDENCIES?

Tags: meson-build

I have a project whose build options are complicated enough that I have to run several external scripts during the configuration process.  If these scripts, or the files that they read, are changed, then configuration needs to be re-run.

Currently the project uses Autotools, and I can express this requirement using the [`CONFIG_STATUS_DEPENDENCIES` variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Rebuilding.html#index-CONFIG_005fSTATUS_005fDEPENDENCIES).  I'm experimenting with porting the build process to Meson and I can't find an equivalent.  Is there currently an equivalent, or do I need to file a feature request?

For concreteness, a snippet of the `meson.build` in progress:

```
pymod = import('python')
python = pymod.find_installation('python3')
svf_script = files('scripts/compute-symver-floor')
svf = run_command(python, svf_script, files('lib'),
                  host_machine.system())
if svf.returncode() == 0
  svf_results = svf.stdout().split('\n')
  SYMVER_FLOOR = svf_results[0].strip()
  SYMVER_FILE  = svf_results[2].strip()

else
  error(svf.stderr())
endif

# next line is a fake API expressing the thing I can't figure out how to do
meson.rerun_configuration_if_files_change(svf_script, SYMVER_FILE)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what [`custom_target()`](https://mesonbuild.com/Reference-manual.html#custom_target) is for.

### Minimal example

```
svf_script = files('svf_script.sh')
svf_depends = files('config_data_1', 'config_data_2') # files that svf_script.sh reads

svf = custom_target('svf_config', command: svf_script, depend_files: svf_depends, build_by_default: true, output: 'fake')
```

This creates a custom target named `svf_config`. When out of date, it runs the `svf_script` command. It depends on the files in the `svf_depends` file object, as well as 
all the files listed in the `command` keyword argument (i.e. the script itself).

You can also specify other targets as dependencies using the `depends` keyword argument.

---

`output` is set to `'fake'` to stop meson from complaining about a missing output keyword argument. Make sure that there is a file of the same name in the corresponding build directory to stop the target from always being considered out-of-date. Alternatively, if your configure script(s) generate output files, you could list them in this array.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't think you understood the question.  I am not looking for a way to make the `svf_script` get run in every build.  I am looking for a way to tell Meson that it needs to redo the _configuration process_ (the stuff that happens when you do `meson <builddir>` in a fresh source tree) if the svf_script changes.  In other words, it needs to treat the svf_script like `meson.build`.

Comment: I don't understand why you would ever need to do that. Could you elaborate? You can make virtually any aspect of meson.build dynamic and dependent on the output of a certain script. Dependencies, new targets, outputs, inputs, it can all be dynamic without having to re-run the setup.